# Changing Specific Bit in a column in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to change a specific bit in oracle database based on bit position.
I had found some related links but couldn't get the desired result.
For eg value is 11110 and we want to reset bit from position 2 .
The result would be 10110 in the form '1' '0' '1' '1' '0'.
Please help with the same .

Comment: That's not resetting bit position 2.  Resetting bit position 2 would be 11010.  Bits normally start numbering from 0, from the right.

Comment: Okay ,counting from LSB we can suppose it to be at position 3.Please help with how can i achieve that

Comment: `SELECT col & ~(1 << 3)` should do that, but it would still be `10110`, not `10111`, because bit 0 was already clear.

Comment: Apologies,My Bad , I want that value only on giving a position in where clause

Comment: How do you store the value?

Comment: In char type column

Comment: Then it is not a bit you want to change, it's a character. You said you want to change a bit in 11110, which is the number 30. But you are not storing 30, you are storing '11110'. Correct? And you want to make the second character a '0'? That is mere string manipulation; take the first character, then a zero, then everything from the third character on. You can do this with `SUBSTR` for instance.

Comment: i tried with substr but getting character to  number  conversion error.Also used to_char but didn't work

Comment: This is weird. Numbers are not involved. It is all substrings and string concatenation. Show your query, if you want an explanation of what you did wrong. I've posted an answer with the very simple string manipluation that you actually need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing a string, where you want to replace the second character from the left with the character '0'. You can use [SUBSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/SUBSTR.html#GUID-C8A20B57-C647-4649-A379-8651AA97187E) for this.

```
select 
  substr(code, 1, 1) -- first character
  || 
  '0' -- the '0' at the second position
  ||
  substr(code, 3) -- everything from the third character to the end
from codes;
```

Answer (score 0):

`substr` and concatenation is probably best for a simple case like this, but you could also look at `regex_replace`:

```
with demo (str) as
    ( select '11111' from dual )
select str as original
     , regexp_replace(str, '^(.{1})(.{1})(.*)$', '\10\3') as replaced
from   demo;

ORIGINAL REPLACED
-------- ---------
11111    10111
```

```
with demo (str) as
    ( select 'Stack' from dual )
select str as original
     , regexp_replace(str, '^(.{1})(.{1})(.*)$', '\1n\3') as replaced
from   demo;

ORIGINAL REPLACED
-------- ---------
Stack    Snack
```

`\1` and `\3` refer to the 1st and 3rd expressions in round brackets.

The `{1}` length specifiers aren't really needed here, but just included in case you need to adjust the position and length of the character you want to replace. For example, replacing a two character substring might look like this:

```
with demo (str) as
    ( select 'Sneeze' from dual )
select str as original
     , regexp_replace(str, '^(.{2})(.{2})(.*)$', '\1oo\3') as replaced
from   demo;

ORIGINAL REPLACED
-------- ---------
Sneeze   Snooze
```

Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/x7c7P2SX
Regex breakdown: https://regex101.com/r/uLCiLu/1